# Добавление ассоциативного массива в другой массив - PHP

Tags: php, массивы, json, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте!

Для создания JSON объекта мне необходимо к массиву добавить другой ассоциативный массив:

```
$array = array('first'=>array('1'=>'2'));
```

При обычной инициализации вложенного массива и последующей конвертации в JSON я получаю строку:

```
{"first":{"1":"2"}}
```

С которой удобно работать.

В моем случае я в цикле собираю ассоциативный массив и единственный способ добавить в массив другой массив такой:

```
$first_array = array('1'=>'value');
$array_main['key'][] = $first_array;
```

Но тогда json_encode выдает строку:`{"key":[{"1":"value"}]}`, который в последствии не очень удобно разбирать.
Метод array_push не умеет добавлять массивы, только значения.
Есть ли какой-нибудь способ нормально сформировать JSON? Заранее спасибо!

UPD:
В общем нужно, чтобы при добавлении к $array_main['key'], на выходе получилось `{"key":{"1":"value"}}` а не `{"key":[{"1":"value"}]}`

Comment: `$array_main['key'][1] = '2'` так то вы не можете сделать? какой результат вы хотите получить, и зачем добавлять элементы массива, если вы хотите (вроде как) вписать нужные ключи? ну или `$array_main['key'] = $first_array` получите `{key: {1 : 'value', ...}}`

Comment: Если хотите объединить несколько массивов, откройте  строку (json_decode) затем используйте array_merge(array1,array2). После конвертируйте обратно в json.

Comment: Как раз проблема в том, что если я напишу $array_main['key'] = $first_array, то т.к. это происходит в цикле, то в нужном ключе, будет записана только последняя итерация.
Смысл в том, что key - несколько значений, но они могут повторяться, поэтому в массив $array_main['key'] записывается соответствующий массив с помощью $array_main['key'][] = $first_array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял задачу

```
<?php
$arr1 = array('zero' => 0, 'one' => 2, 'two' => 2);
$arr2 = array('0' => 1, '1' => 2, '2' => 3);

$i = 0;
foreach ($arr1 as $key=>$vol) {

    $array[$key] = array_slice($arr2, $i, 1, true );
    $i+= 1;
}
```

На выходе будет такое:

```
 print_r: Array ( [zero] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [one] => Array ( [1] => 2 ) [two] => Array ( [2] => 3 ) )
 var_dump: array(3) { ["zero"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(1) } ["one"]=> array(1) { [1]=> int(2) } ["two"]=> array(1) { [2]=> int(3) } }
```

В общем, прогоните результирующий массив через json_encode с опцией JSON_FORCE_OBJECT

```
json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Получите {"zero":{"0":1},"one":{"1":2},"two":{"2":3}}